# Lost connection to shared VirtualBox Ubuntu folder from host Windows 10 PC

Tags: windows-10, virtualbox, network-shares, samba, ubuntu-16.04

**The Problem**

I have Samba shared folders on Ubuntu Server 16.04 that runs in VirtualBox on a Windows 10 PC. It was working for the last couple of weeks but now I can't connect from the Windows PC. The server still runs, serves files with Apache2, has the same IP etc. How do I restore access to the shared folders?

**Details**

When I startup the VirtualBox Ubuntu instance I can still discover it on the network (using Windows Explorer), but the previously mapped drives no longer work, and I can't open the discovered Ubuntu instance. I get `"Network Error - Windows cannot access \\{name of my Ubuntu instance} Check the spelling of the name..."` etc.

I've also checked the samba logs (log.smbd) and everything looks fine there. I've tried restarting smbd too.

These are the settings I've previously added to the end of /etc/samba/smb.conf:

```
[UbuntuBenShare]
path = /home/ben
public = yes
guest ok = yes
writable = yes
force user = ben

[UbuntuWWWShare]
public = yes
guest ok = yes
writable = yes
force user = ben
```

I'd expect that when I double click on the discovered Ubuntu instance from Windows that two folders `[UbuntuBenShare]` and `[UbuntuWWWShare]` would show up - that's what happened when I originally mapped them.

I've also tried `net use` from cmd and get "There are no connections in the list"

Finally, I am able to ping the server from the Windows PC successfully.

**It seems that the problem is not the network but something with the sharing or permissions. What can I do to connect to the shared folders from the PC?**

Answer (score 0):

Try reinstalling **Virtual Guest Additions** which are required in order to use *Shared folders* properly. This can be achieved by selecting *Insert Guest Additions CD Image* from the *Devices* menu of your guest VM window.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the firewall (`ufw`) was enabled while mucking about with SSL settings and that was blocking it. After disabling it, it worked again. I'll need to work out how to configure `ufw` to allow Samba to still work. <sup>[@Ben](https://superuser.com/revisions/1261783/2)</sup>